# parse_url for youtube link

Tags: php

I'm using the following code just to convert any URL to starts with `http://` or `https://`
but this function makes problem with exact type urls as example

```
$url = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss'; // url without http://

function convertUrl ($url){
$parts = parse_url($url);
$returl = "";
if (empty($parts['scheme'])){
$returl = "http://".$parts['path'];
} else if ($parts['scheme'] == 'https'){
$returl = "https://".$parts['host'].$parts['path'];
} else {
$returl = $url;
}
return $returl;
}

$url = convertUrl($url);
echo $url;
```

the output

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch
```

expected output as i want

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss
```

as i mainly use it just to fix any url without `http://` so is there any way to edit this function so it can pass all urls with `=_` as shown in the example ! as it really annoying me ~ thanks

Comment: The `GET` params are inside `$parts['query']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to get:

```
$query = $parts['query'];
```

Because that's the query section of the URL.

You can modify your function to do this:

```
function convertUrl ($url){
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $returl = "";
    if (empty($parts['scheme'])){
        $returl = "http://".$parts['path'];
    } else if ($parts['scheme'] == 'https'){
        $returl = "https://".$parts['host'].$parts['path'];
    } else {
        $returl = $url;
    }
    // Define variable $query as empty string.
    $query = '';
    if ($parts['query']) {
        // If the query section of the URL exists, concatenate it to the URL.
        $query = '?' . $parts['query'];
    }
    return $returl . $query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you really care about is the first part of the passed URL, how about an alternate approach?

```
$pattern = '#^http[s]?://#i';
if(preg_match($pattern, $url) == 1) { // this url has proper scheme
    return $url;
} else {
    return 'http://' . $url;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is awesome and smart , gonna use it better than parse_url idea.

Answer (score 2):

http://codepad.org/bJ7pY8bg

```
<?php
$url1 = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss';
$url2 = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss';
$url3 = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss';
function urlfix($url) {
return preg_replace('/^.*www\./',"https://www.",$url);
}
echo urlfix($url1)."\n";
echo urlfix($url2),"\n";
echo urlfix($url3),"\n";
```

Output:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ss
```